# table-cell split when there is more then 2 divs

Tags: css, html, css-tables

They all standing now all next to each other (with table-cell) but is it possible to break them up with a css rule? So that there is only standing 2 divs next to each other?

I can not modify the HTML only the css...

This on a pc monitor:(this is good)
▆ ▆ ▆ ▆ ▆ ▆ ▆

But on a ipad i want to have:
▆ ▆
▆ ▆
▆ ▆
▆

Comment: what are the details of the two classes you have assigned? You could make the parent element smaller forcing them break to the next line if you are using float.

Comment: John, I have add the CSS... :-)

Comment: All adjacent elements with a display of table-cell will appear in an unbreakable row.  That's how the display property works.  Your only option is to not use that display property for device widths where you know the elements do not fit properly in a row.

Comment: @cimmanon, but now i can use the pixels for the paddings between the boxes (pixels/em). When i use float option then thats not working (50% boxes with 20px margin it to width for a 100% box). 

Then the second option is to change the css table to a block element and for the kolom class the inline-block with the box-sizing tag but thats not supported with all IE versions...

Comment: It's interesting that you're concerned about IE's support for box-sizing because IE8+ is required for both box-sizing and `display: table/table-row/table-cell` (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing and http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

Comment: For IE old version , serve *display:inline;zoom:1; to blocks element you want to display as inline-block. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hmEqD I could have make an aswer with that, but discussion goes here now and it takes its meaning here :)

Comment: @cimmanon, Ahh stupid! I was thinking IE8 was not supported! Then now all my problems are over, thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your css like

```
.row .kolom {
        display :inline;
        float:left;
        padding:0;
    }
```

Comment: Floating an element automatically modifies the display property, so there's no point in specifying one here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically use it for other devices then it would be better idea to go for CSS media queries. This would help you to specify style depending on device width and then it would be the matter of setting appropriate widths to the containers

Hope this link would be helpfull http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPad